# Почему сеттеры не устанавливают значения переменным экземпляра класса?

Tags: php, ооп

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     class Polygon {
         private $width, $height;

         function __cosnstruct(float $w = 4, float $h = 5) {
             $this->width = $w;
             $this->height = $h;
         }

         public function setWidth(float $w) {$this->$width = $w;}
         public function setHeight(float $h) {$this->$height = $h;}

         public function getWidth() {return $this->width;}
         public function getHeight() {return $this->height;}
     }

     class Rectangle extends Polygon {
         public function area() {
             return ($this->getWidth() * $this->getHeight());
         }
     }

     class Triangle extends Polygon {
         public function area() {
             return ($this->getWidth() * $this->getHeight() / 2);
         }
     }

     $rect = new Rectangle();
     $rect->setWidth(2.5);
     $rect->setHeight(4);
     $triangle = new Triangle();
     $triangle->setWidth(7);
     $triangle->setHeight(6);
     echo "Площадь прямоугольника равна: " . $rect->area() . "<br>";
     echo "Площадь треугольника равна: " . $triangle->area() . "<br>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Выводится 0 0, а не как ожидается 10 21
Почему так? Как это исправить?

Comment: Как у вас что-то может выводить, если `$this->$width` ?

Comment: @РустамГимранов мде.. Я не заметил)) Долго код высматривал на ошибки и так и не увидел)) Спасибо)

Comment: @РустамГимранов можете написать ответ, и я помечу как решение)

Comment: Зачем на процессе обучения отключаете отображение ошибок? В php.ini выставьте `display_errors=On`.

Comment: **display_errors=On**

Comment: @РустамГимранов да, это тоже нашёл. Стоит on

Comment: display_errors = on

Comment: @РустамГимранов у меня в папке с PHP два файла php-development.ini и php-production.ini. В php-development.ini по дефолту стояло display_errors: On, а php-production.ini стояло Off, я изменил на On, но всё равно ошибку не выдаёт если написать $this->$width

Comment: @JustLearn переименуйте `php-development.ini` на `php.ini`.